# How to convert rectangle to bitmap in wpf

Tags: wpf

Actually i am trying to convert rectangle to bitmap in wpf. Here what i have done means, First i have added that rectangle to canvas and then i am converting to bitmap. Here i have written the code for adding rectangle under form_load and to convert it to bitmap, i have written code under buttonclick. Then it is creating bitmap perfectly.

form_load....

```
Canvas can = new Canvas();
can.ClipToBounds=true;

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect.Height = 200;
rect.Width = 50;
can.Height = 200;
can.Width = 50;
rect.Fill = color.................
can.Children.add(rect);
```

button_click

```
TargetBitmapRenderer bit = new TargetBitmapRenderer((int)can.ActualWidth,(int)Can.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
......
.....
```

Above code working perfectly...
But if write the code under button clik in formload event,
The actual width and actual height of the canvas is zero that is why it is creating error....

BUt i want to create bitmaps dynamically in single block of code... 
Then Please suggest me some waye to achieve this.Thank you...

Comment: I have a feeling that you didn't copy and paste this code from your IDE. There are several spelling mistakes that definitely won't compile. Please show us your *actual* code so that we don't waste time with irrelevant issues.

Answer (score 0):

Though you have added the rectangle to the Canvas, Canvas haven't got a chance to properly measure and render it into itself. So you may want to explicitly call Measure and arrange on the canvas. If it was in XAML, because of being part of the main visual-tree, Measure and arrange will get called automatically and you will see the results.

```
can.children.add(rect);
can.Measure(new Size(200,50));
can.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 200, 50));
```